# Displaying last argument in scheme code

Tags: scheme

I want to be able to determine the last value that was calculated in my tests for a compiler (scheme -> cisc-assembly) that I'm testing.

I already have a script to automate most of the testing and compilation procedures, but I want to automate the comparison of the compiler's output (stored in register #0 [R0] and printed), with [chez](http://www.scheme.com/)'s (chez is the standard for the compiler) output (no idea how to "grab" the last calculated argument, which is what I want to compare).

Is there a way to do this? or will I have to create duplicate tests, one of which with hard-coded print ("display") on the last argument?

Example of a simple test file:

```
;---------------------
((lambda (x) x) #t)
;---------------------
```

This compiles to a rather complicated and long .c file with integrated-cisc assembly that stores the last expression's result in a special register.

Is there a way to echo the last result of

```
((lambda (x) x) #t)
```

(which is #t) **without the obvious solution of modifying the file manually** based on chez-scheme's evaluation??

Thanks in advance for any help or leads.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Do you have a concise example?

Comment: I'm updating the question to include more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the last 'result' comes from a Scheme expression, then you can use `eval`, for example:

```
> (eval '((lambda (x) x) 'yes) (scheme-report-environment 5))
yes
```

Comment: Is there a way to "eval" a file?

Comment: There is a function (load <filename>) after which you could 'eval' variables from the file.  But you'll need to be careful about environments.